# Вставка данных в Pivot-таблицу

Tags: php, laravel

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function elements()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Element::class);
    }

}

class Element extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }

}
```

Связующая таблица называется "product_element".

```
class MainController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $product = Product::find(3);
        $product->elements()->attach([19, 20, 12]);

        return view('base', ['r' => Element::get(['id', 'name'])]);
    }
}
```

Выдает ошибку:
"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'element_product' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `element_product` (`element_id`, `product_id`) values (19, 3), (20, 3), (12, 3))"

Comment: Посмотри в базе есть ли эта таблица. Если правильно составлены связи при миграции должно появится три таблицы

Comment: нет ее, таблица в базе называется "product_element"

Comment: небольшой туториал без воды https://medium.com/@afrazahmad090/laravel-many-to-many-relationship-explained-822b554c1973

Comment: Ага, получилось. В документации этого не видел. Спасибо большое!